# Dart - How to parse a string from ";" and :

Tags: parsing, dart

I want to parse a string that looks like this "str1:1234;str2:1234;" and get the values and keys.
How can i do this in Dart ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this should do the job:

```
void main() {
  final string = 'str1:1234;str2:1234;';
  final map = Map.fromEntries(string
      .split(';')
      .where((e) => e.isNotEmpty)
      .map((e) => e.split(':'))
      .map((e) => MapEntry(e[0], e[1])));
  
  print(map); // {str1: 1234, str2: 1234}
}
```

Inspired from the RegExp solution I also made this which are shorter:

```
void main() {
  final string = 'str1:1234;str2:1234;';
  final map = Map.fromEntries(RegExp(r'(.+?):(.+?);')
      .allMatches(string)
      .map((m) => MapEntry(m.group(1), m.group(2))));

  print(map); // {str1: 1234, str2: 1234}
}
```

Comment: It looks like the second string is a number, so you might also want to parse that. The RegExp solution can be written as a map literal: `var map = {for (var m in RegExp(r'(.*?):(.+?);').allMatches(string)) m[0]: int.parse(m[1])};`.